# Xcode path to Prefix Header - new target

Tags: ios, xcode, precompiled-headers

In my original target, for Prefix Header in build settings I have this:

```
AppName/Supporting Files/AppName-Prefix.pch
```

I added a new target, for which I want to have a different prefix header.

So I made this the path for the 2nd target:

```
AppNameTwo/Supporting Files/AppNameTwo-Prefix.pch
```

However I get build errors:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/path/AppName/AppName2/Supporting Files/AppName-Prefix.pch
```

Why is it inserting "AppName" into the path, before /AppName2?

The folders AppName and AppName2 are both in the root of my project, in the same directory as the AppName.xcodeproj file.

Answer (score 3):

`${PROJECT_DIR}/AppNameTwo/Supporting Files/AppNameTwo-Prefix.pch` has worked for me in a similar situation.

Comment: That results in the same path, because ${PROJECT_DIR} = /path/AppName

Comment: How do I change ${PROJECT_DIR}?

Comment: @soleil ${PROJECT_DIR} should give you the directory where your Xcode project file is. If your project is set up correctly you should have the dierctories ${PROJECT_DIR}/AppNameOne and ${PROJECT_DIR}/AppeNameTwo containing your source code files.